# Sample code to create pdf programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to iphone.

Is there any sample code or tutorial.

Also need a sample code for plist

Please help me.

Comment: It is impossible to answer to that question. What is it you want to do? Without telling us, what do you expect us to answer?

Comment: u first search with google.... try to avoid like type questions  http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/ for pdf creation

Comment: What you really need is a good iOS programming book, actually, but still I am happy to help where I can.

Comment: @Thomas below Amit Patel's answer was correct try to implement this

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here I Have Best Example of how to create .pdf file in iPhone :)

**PdfGenerationDemoViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define kBorderInset            20.0
#define kBorderWidth            1.0
#define kMarginInset            10.0

//Line drawing
#define kLineWidth              1.0

@interface PdfGenerationDemoViewController : UIViewController
{
    CGSize pageSize;
}

- (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

**PdfGenerationDemoViewController.m**

```
#import "PdfGenerationDemoViewController.h"

@interface PdfGenerationDemoViewController (Private)
- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath;
- (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNum;
- (void) drawBorder;
- (void) drawText;
- (void) drawLine;
- (void) drawHeader;
- (void) drawImage;
@end

@implementation PdfGenerationDemoViewController

#pragma mark - Private Methods
- (void) drawBorder
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, kBorderInset, pageSize.width-kBorderInset*2, pageSize.height-kBorderInset*2);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kBorderWidth);
    CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);
}

- (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNumber
{
    NSString* pageNumberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %d", pageNumber];
    UIFont* theFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

    CGSize pageNumberStringSize = [pageNumberString sizeWithFont:theFont
                                   constrainedToSize:pageSize
                                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect stringRenderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset,
                                   pageSize.height - 40.0,
                                   pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset,
                                   pageNumberStringSize.height);

    [pageNumberString drawInRect:stringRenderingRect withFont:theFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
}

- (void) drawHeader
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 1.0);

    NSString *textToDraw = @"Pdf Demo - iOSLearner.com";

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];

    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
}

- (void) drawText
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    NSString *textToDraw = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.";

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font
                               constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset-2*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) 
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, stringSize.height);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect 
                  withFont:font
             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap
                 alignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];

}

- (void) drawLine
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kLineWidth);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(kMarginInset + kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(pageSize.width - 2*kMarginInset -2*kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CGContextClosePath(currentContext);    
    CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

- (void) drawImage
{
    UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
    [demoImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - demoImage.size.width/2)/2, 350, demoImage.size.width/2, demoImage.size.height/2)];
}

- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    NSInteger currentPage = 0;
    BOOL done = NO;
    do 
    {
        //Start a new page.
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);

        //Draw a page number at the bottom of each page.
        currentPage++;
        [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

        //Draw a border for each page.
        [self drawBorder];

        //Draw text fo our header.
        [self drawHeader];

        //Draw a line below the header.
        [self drawLine];

        //Draw some text for the page.
        [self drawText];

        //Draw an image
        [self drawImage];
        done = YES;
    } 
    while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
}
@end
```

Comment: This is really a nice one.Thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @THOMAS - all d best...and u r welcome :)

Comment: how to modify the above code to work with multiple pages of pdf

Comment: @TheKing do you have any idea to work with multiple pages of pdf ?????

Answer (score 1):

Apple's [Drawing and Printing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) is your friend. Basically, if you can draw to the screen, you can draw to a PDF on iOS (and Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

You may find it a bit advanced tutorial but [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1) fine tutorial by Ray Wenderlich will really help you out and as far as plit is concerned, you should Google it first as you can find plenty of them.

Best wishes,

Farrukh Javeid

Answer (score 0):

```
CFURLRef pdfURL = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), CFSTR("iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf"), NULL, NULL);
        PDFfile = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);
        CFRelease(pdfURL);    
 CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(PDFfile,currentpage);

        context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        CGContextFillRect(context,self.bounds);   
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -1.0, [self bounds].size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page,  kCGPDFArtBox, [self bounds], 0, true));
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);    
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);
        CGAffineTransform transform = aspectFit(CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox),
                                                    CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context));

           CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height));
```