# How to create a multiple page PDF in ios6?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In ["Sample code to create pdf programmatically"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776930/sample-code-to-create-pdf-programmatically/12776991#12776991) there is code for generating a PDF with multiple pages, but I can't understand where I have to put or implement that code .

First answer: generate PDF that I've already done in my project.

Second Answer: for multiple page in that I am confuse. Can anyone tell me where I put this code to generate a PDF with multiple pages?

Comment: If you show your code your to create a single-page PDF then we can tell you how to modify it for multiple pages.

Comment: It may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483933/create-pdf-with-multiple-pages

Answer (score 2):

For creating multiple pages

Define **NSInteger currentPage = 0;** at the top in .m file

and in  generatePdfWithFilePath method write

```
-(void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
    NSLog(@"\n==========\n \t the file path==  %@",thefilePath);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

    do
    {        
           currentPage++;

           if(currentPage == 1) 
              pageSize= CGSizeMake(612,2350);
           else
              pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 2000);

           [self drawBorder];

           //Draw text fo our header.
           [self drawHeader];

           //Draw a line below the header.
           [self drawLine];

           //Draw some text for the page.
           [self drawText];

           //Draw an image
           [self drawImage];

    }while (currentPage !=2); //You can write required page number here

    currentPage=0;

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Comment: @Jagdish what issue you are facing?

Comment: Your do while() logic is not working, Now i have done with other way (for loop)..

Comment: Have you declared `NSInteger currentPage = 0;` ?