# how to create multiple pages pdf programmatically in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, pdf, nsmutablearray

I have one image array and I am trying to create pdf with that images.how can i create multiple pages pdf file.
I checked one tutorial but its not working for me.
 [How to create a multiple page PDF in ios6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775124/how-to-create-a-multiple-page-pdf-in-ios6)
Please help me

Comment: It may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483933/create-pdf-with-multiple-pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
NSArray *pageArray = yourImageArray;

NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectMake(0, 0, 595, 842), nil);

for (UIImage *theImage in pageArray) {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(theImage, 0.5);
    CGDataProviderRef dp = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpegData);
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dp, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    [[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theImage.size.width, theImage.size.height)];
}

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
return pdfData;
```

Answer (score 0):

For starting each new page in the pdf, use

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight), nil);
```